# How to find the characteristics of diffusion equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Give a 1-D diffusion equation:
$$
u_t = ku_{xx} \quad (-\infty<x<\infty,0<t<\infty)\\
u(x,0) = \phi(x)
$$
I am reading Section2.4 of ``PDE:an introduction''(2rd edition) by Walter A. Strauss. The author says that the characteristics for the diffusion equation are just the lines t = constant. But I don't know hot to verify it.

Or is it a wrong conclusion?

And if it is wrong, hwo to get the right characteristics for the diffusion equation?

Comment: Since the highest (second order) is $ku_{xx}=0$, the characteristic condition gives $kt'(s)^2=0$, so $t$ is constant.  This is what we expect from a parabolic equation.

Comment: Thank you. I think I misunderstood the definition of characteristics for the equation.